# WPF UI not refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I have a problem to refresh my UI in a wpf / mvvm project.

When I log out there is a action on UI to display "waiting" object and then do a long process.

All codes I present are not complete

```
private void btnPower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // IHM changes
      btnRightMenuShow.IsEnabled = false;
      btnRightMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      StationWindowViewModel stnWindowVM = (StationWindowViewModel)DataContext;
      stnWindowVM.ProgressMode = LoadingProcessViewModel.ProgressMode.Sending;

      // PRocess
      if (stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.CanExecute(null))
      {
          stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.Execute(null);
      }
}
```

Like this the ihm is like frozen during the process and never refresh() before the application ended.

I first try to use a background worker like

```
private void btnPower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // IHM changes
      btnRightMenuShow.IsEnabled = false;
      btnRightMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      StationWindowViewModel stnWindowVM = (StationWindowViewModel)DataContext;
      stnWindowVM.ProgressMode = LoadingProcessViewModel.ProgressMode.Sending;

      // PRocess
      powerOffWorker.RunWorkerAsync(stnWindowVM);
}

private void powerOffWorker_DoWork(object Sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      if (stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.CanExecute(null))
      {
          stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.Execute(null);
      }
}
```

In this case the IHM is refreshed but i have threading errors with some code trying to access object created by parent thread on main process (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it)

So i try to use a Dispatcher like

```
private void btnPower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // IHM changes
      btnRightMenuShow.IsEnabled = false;
      btnRightMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      StationWindowViewModel stnWindowVM = (StationWindowViewModel)DataContext;
      stnWindowVM.ProgressMode = LoadingProcessViewModel.ProgressMode.Sending;

      // PRocess
      this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
      {
          if (stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.CanExecute(null))
          {
              stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.Execute(null);
          }
      }));
}
```

I also try dispatcher inside backgrounworker but with those dispatcher i don't have anymore problem with calling thread but the UI is not updating.

**EDIT**

This is my test for async/await implementation

```
private void btnPower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // IHM changes
  btnRightMenuShow.IsEnabled = false;
  btnRightMenuShow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  StationWindowViewModel stnWindowVM = (StationWindowViewModel)DataContext;
  stnWindowVM.ProgressMode = LoadingProcessViewModel.ProgressMode.Sending;

  // PRocess
  PowerOffAsync(stnWindowVM);
}

private async void PowerOffAsync(StationWindowViewModel stnWindowVM)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.CanExecute(null))
         {
            stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.Execute(null);
        }
    });
}
```

In the PowerOffCmd process ther is some operation on object like list which gives error with calling thread...

Comment: tl;dr: what is an ihm?

Comment: hi, sorry by IHM i mean the "visual" / window seen by the user.

Comment: Any particular reasons why you're not using `async/await` instead ?

Comment: i'm not expert on the subject and i didn't try to use async/await so i will

Comment: I wrote an answer that is not specific to MVVM, but you'll see a complete answer for using async/await and progressbar while processing a long task. It might be of interest. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212664/7692463

Comment: At the moment i reproduce the same behaviour if i set async/await the window is refreshed but i have a problem with The calling thread which cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. And if i add a dispatcher inside the async/await i solve the thread problem but the window is not refreshed anymore...

Comment: @lavoyech Edit and  post your async implementation.

Comment: i post the implementation

Comment: @lavoyech try to see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probem is that you try to invoke the dispatcher in the awaiting call instead of calling it where you need to work on UI.

Basically, if you do

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.CanExecute(null))
        {
            stnWindowVM.PowerOffCmd.Execute(null);
        }
    }));
});
```

You're doing it wrong since you're processing your async work on the UI thread the whole time.

One work around you can try is invoke the dispatcher in your `PowerOffCmd` where it gives you the error. This way, everything except where you need to work on UI thread (modifying controls for example) will execute on a separate thread which will assure that you're UI stay responsive.

Comment: So if i understand i should be more accurate and use Dispatcher.invoke() for every line which gives thread error inside PowerOffCmd?

Comment: I can't say if this is the best solution for your particular case since I'm not familiar with your architecture, but it will definitely work.

Comment: ok i'm going to try and come back to you after. thanks for your time

Comment: @lavoyech If you're always doing the samething in a lot of place in your code, consider writing  a static method that invoke the dispatcher and does the work on your object passed as a parameter. Then call it when you need in your `PowerOffCmd`.